# Polygon support in Python S2 library

Tags: python, polygon

I want to get the Cell Ids of all the cells lies in a polygon with specific levels.

https://github.com/sidewalklabs/s2sphere

This library is the Python implementation of Google S2 Library.
It provides a function to get the region covering of a region.

```
region_coverer = s2sphere.RegionCoverer()
region_coverer.get_covering(region)
```

I have seen all the examples but couldn't find where the region is a polygon. In all examples either it is a rectangle or a circle.

I just wanted to know if it is possible to get all the cells in a Polygon using S2sphere library or are there any other library implementation s2 geometry which provides this support?

I have used java s2 library. It provides support for polygon but couldn't find any support in python.

Comment: Have you found any solution after this long time?

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this...